# How can I ignore deceleration from event.acceleration in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, accelerometer, devicemotion

I'm trying to have an event occur when the phone first starts moving. This triggers just fine. However, I am running into a problem: deceleration is measured similarly to acceleration. When I stop moving the device, I see another spike. Any suggestions on how to ignore that second spike?

The following code gives me "huzzah!" when I first move the phone and when I stop moving it. I only want the trigger on the first movement. I got the pertinent functions and most of the variables defined here. Not the full extent of the script, but all the parts of this functionality.

```
var elmt = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var acceleration = eventData.acceleration;
var speed = 0;
speed = round(acceleration.y);
elmt.splice(0,1);
elmt.push(speed);
speedSmoothed=elmt.average();
                                          //Rounding function
function round(val) {
  var amt = 10;
  return Math.round(val * amt) /  amt;
}
                                        //Averaging function for the array
Array.prototype.average=function(){
var sum=0;
var j=0;
for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++){
    if(isFinite(this[i])){
      sum=sum+parseFloat(this[i]);
       j++;
      }
    }
if(j===0){
    return 0;
  }else{
      return sum/j;
   }
  }
                                            //trigger
if (speedSmoothed>1.5){
    console.log("Huzzah!");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

a few hours of thinking later, I got a little crafty. Enough to reliably behave like I want it to anyway.

```
if (speedSmoothed>1.5 && elmt[0]>elmt[4]){
 console.log("Huzzah!");
 }
```